# How do I print the amount of digits between 0 -9 in an array with a specific size?

Tags: arrays, c

I have an array that its size is 15 and has a positive digit in each element. How do I count how many times each digit between 0 til 9 has been in my array and print out " o has been appears x times, 1 appears y times, 2 appears z times" and on till 9

Comment: Create an array of 10 elements that correspond to digits and then increase the element for the given digit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do (assuming numbers in first array are only one digit):

```
let numbersCount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] //each index is for numbers from 0 to 9
let myArray = [1, 1, 1, 2,...] // array of numbers with positive digits
myArray.foreach(num => numbersCount[num]++);
console.log(numbersCount) // numbersCount = [0, 3, 1, ...];
```

which 0 is the count of 0 in myArray, 3 is the count of 1, 1 is the count of 2, ... .

Answer (score 0):

The logic is similar to counting sort. I think it will be good for you to read the explanation about counting sort: [Counting Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/).

The following code might answer your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 15
#define COUNT_ARR_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int arr[ARR_SIZE] = {0,1,1,2,2,2,9,3,4,3,2,5,6,7,8};
    int countArr[COUNT_ARR_SIZE] = {0};
    
    for(i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        countArr[arr[i]]++;
        
    for(i = 0; i < COUNT_ARR_SIZE; i++)
        printf("Number %d appears %d times in the array\n", i,countArr[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The code is written in C language.